# Вызвать хук с дополнительными параметрами

Tags: php, wordpress

В `woocommerce` есть хук

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_stock_quantity','product_get_stock_quantity', 10, 2);
```

Как вызвать этот хук, чтобы можно было передать в него дополнительные параметры?
Он принимает только два параметра, а нужно передавать в него дополнительные параметры
Этот хук `woocommerce_product_variation_get_stock_quantity` вызывается так:

```
            $variation = wc_get_product( $item['variation_id'] );
            $old_quantity = $variation->get_stock_quantity();
```

Как передать в функцию `$variation->get_stock_quantity()` дополнительные параметры?

т.е. если в `do_action` определено только два параметра, можно ли как-то переопределить, чтобы принимал 3 параметра?

Comment: Что конкретно вам нужно еще передать? В вуке невероятное кол-во глобальных переменных, которые ты можешь получить где угодно

Comment: @Krya, хук `woocommerce_product_variation_get_stock_quantity` возвращает текущее количество товара, а мне нужно именно на странице checkout вызвать этот хук,  но передать дополнительные параметры, чтобы именно на странице checkout после подтверждения заказа вызвался хук с дополнительным параметром. Этот хук срабатывает при загрузке страницы корзины, при начальной загрузке корзины дополнительный параметр не нужно передавать

Comment: нашёл похожий вопрос https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/290030/passing-additional-parameters-to-add-filter-callable

Comment: нужно что-то типа такого: `add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', function() use ($param1, $param2) { return get_expiration(null, null, null, $param1, $param2); } , 10, 3 );`

Comment: т.е. при начальной загрузке корзины дополнительный параметр не нужно передавать, а после подтверждения заказа доп-й параметр нужно передавать